# Normal distribution of large random strings

Tags: distribution, probability, random

In coding theory I have met a problem:

Two random strings are chosen from a field of F(2,n), i.e. every bit can only take 0 and 1, and the strings are of n bits long.

Now, we would like to know the distribution of the number of different bits between the two strings. (i.e. Hamming Distance)

Experiment shows that it is very close to 0.5, and that the distribution is a normal distribution. Is there some way to prove this?

(Simple model would be like, I throw two coins for n times and count the number of differences for instance 0.49n; and repeat this experiment for sufficiently large k times. What's the distribution of this number of differences over k?)

Comment: Hello, this question is good for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about statistics without a connection to programming

Answer (score 0):

The number of different bits is the sum of a collection of independent variables (namely an indicator variable which is 1 if they are different and 0 if they are the same), all of which have finite variance; therefore the distribution of that number is approximately Gaussian, and becomes more Gaussian as `n` increases.

The exact distribution is binomial, since it is the sum of independent 0/1 variables with constant probability (the indicator variables all have the same probability, namely 1/2 for indicator=1 and 1/2 for indicator=0).

I am working from memory; don't accept this answer without verifying it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Let X and Y be independent random variables whose values are drawn uniformly from the set of binary strings of length n: X, Y ~ U({0,1}<sup>n</sup>).

Let d(X, Y) be the Hamming distance.

Then d(X, Y) is a random variable drawn from a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with n possible events, each of probability p = 0.5: d(X, Y) ~ B(n, 0.5).

Its expectation is 0.5 × n.

Its standard deviation is 0.5 × √n.

Answer (score 0):

If bits are drawn independently with probability 1/2 of getting either a zero or a one, then agreement in position k can be conditioned on the outcome in the k<sup>th</sup> position of the first string - whether that's a zero or a one, the second string has a probability of 1/2 of matching.  That makes the bit-by-bit distributions [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with p=1/2.  Hamming distance is the sum of these Bernoulli outcomes, and the sum of n independent Bernoullis has a [binomial(n,p)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distribution - this is an exact result.  Your experiments should yield a mean of n/2, and a variance of np(1-p) or n/4.  The [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) tells us that the binomial distribution will converge to the normal distribution as n --> infinity. An engineering rule of thumb is that the approximation will be good enough when both np > 10 and n(1-p) > 10.